# Why is my RenderTexture y-flipped?

Tags: c, rendertexture, raylib

When drawing a very simple `RenderTexture` using Raylib, with the following POC code, the texture actually drawn is vertically inverted. Is that normal? If not, what did I do wrong?

```c
#include "raylib.h"

int main() {
  InitWindow(200, 200, "Demo");

  Camera2D camera = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};

  RenderTexture tex = LoadRenderTexture(100, 100);

  BeginTextureMode(tex);
  ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
  DrawText("Raylib", 0, 0, 24, RED);
  EndTextureMode();

  // Main loop
  while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
    BeginDrawing();
    DrawTexture(tex.texture, 0, 0, WHITE);
    EndDrawing();
  }

  CloseWindow();

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

**NOTE:** I ran this command to compile from Fedora Linux: `gcc -o demo demo.c path/to/raylib/libraylib.a -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11`

**NOTE:** I know that displaying it with `DrawTextureRect()` that has a negative height solves the problem, but I find odd that I even have to do that step. I'm looking for an explanation more than a solution.

Comment: There's a couple different ways of explaining this depending on what conventions you follow! First, Y = 0 isn't always the top of the screen. Second, Y = 0 isn't always the top of an image in memory. At some point you might have to flip something because the actual monitor uses Y = 0 as the top by convention. So you could flip the whole image, or you could flip the texture, or you could change the UV coordinates of the quad that your render texture is rendered to, etc... I don't know enough about Raylib to give you an official answer detailing what is conventional for that lib.

Comment: I gave you the whole code, you can try it by yourself! That's my point, there are no fancy shenanigans hidden in a config file, I simply wrote that code, compiled it with `gcc -o demo demo.c path/to/raylib/libraylib.a -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11` (on Linux Fedora) and that's it: the texture is flipped. Note that I'll add the compile command in the question, it may by part of the solution!

Comment: Sorry it looks like you got an old version of my comment before editing. The issue isn't that you didn't provide enough code, I just thought those functions you were calling were more code written by you but I know now they are actually functions from Raylib. I don't know Raylib well enough to answer your questions, I just know that there are different conventions for how to handle coordinate systems and texture orientation so the "right" answer comes down to which conventions Raylib observes.

Comment: FYI, OpenGL uses a coordinate system for textures that many people would consider to be "upside down". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316529/opengl-texture-inverted for example. Sometimes you just need to flip the image vertically when working with it.

Comment: @Romen that makes more sense, thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Adam That's an answer I can get behind. If you're sure enough about that, make it an actual answer and I'll accept it!